# Tradução de um site sem cms

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web, webdesign

Olá, tenho um site apenas em html, css e js. O cliente pediu para inserir um botão de alteração de lingua. Inglês e português apenas. Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma ferramenta ou maneira de fazer este processo apenas usando o js ou se terei que traduzir a página inteira e então criar a ancora redirecionando entre os dois arquivos.

Desde já obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Acho que você teria de usar i18n, você pode usar dois HTML [en e pt], só não sei se seria viável para seu projeto, ou pode inserir o google translate para o seu site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nathan, antigamente existia um recurso do Google tradutor que era possível incluir um botão mas foi removido, então se o seu site é estático talvez criar uma página html em outro idioma seja mais rápido, você pode traduzir colocando a url lá no google tradutor que ele gera uma página traduzida, depois é só você copiar o código fonte, talvez ajude.

Olha o exemplo: https://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=pt-BR&sp=nmt4&tl=en&u=https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/370108/tradu%25C3%25A7%25C3%25A3o-de-um-site-sem-cms&xid=17259,15700022,15700186,15700190,15700248,15700253&usg=ALkJrhiJWUBzVkGYs1dFDEEURXCgFFRgCQ